# python importing path not matching windows 10

Tags: python, import, git-bash, sys

I im using Git bash to open jupyter lab and a notebook file. I want to import a file such as test.py, with a function such as test_func(x). The test.py is in another folder then the working directory. using pwd in the notebook i get something like "C:\Users\Documents\Code_folder\". I have added the path of the test.py using sys.path.insert(1, "C:\Users\Code\), where the test.py is located.

I then have no issues with importing the module, but if i add another module, test_func2(y), and i say run test.test_func2??, i cant find the function, and when running test.test_func??, i see that the output on line: File: "c:\users\code\". I belive is the lower case of the File that gets me the missing module.

Why does this happen, and can i change it in a simple say without changing all my codes?

Edit: test_func2 is another function in test.py

Comment: Do you mean another function (not module?) for test_func2(y)? Where is that located? Try sys.path.append("C:/Users/Code") (you can use forward slashes in your python code it works on windows too)

Comment: i mean another function, not module, sorry.

Comment: Try sys.path.append and let me know if it's still not working, also what is the exact import statement that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

This may simply be an issue with how you're importing. I'm not sure of the internal mechanics of Jupyter, but in a terminal window if you change the module it has to be `reload`ed (reimported.) In Python3 the reload was moved to the `imp` module.

See [stackoverflow:How do I unload (reload) a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-module)

For Jupyter, I assume you have the `import test.py` in a previous window. If you add a function to a `.py` file, just go back to that window and rerun the import...although I'm not sure that will guarantee a reload (since just re-running the command `import test.py` in the terminal Python would ***not*** work.)